# Analysis of cubic /complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

If $z^3+(3+2i)z+(-1+iy)=0$ ( where $i^2=-1$) has one real root, then the value of $y$ does not belongs to :

1. $(2,3)$
2. $(-5,-1)$
3. $(0,1)$
4. $(-2,-1)$

**My try**: *I would like you guys to tell me how to analyze a cubic equation; not just for this particular question but how to analyze a cubic equation in general. Like we have determinant and inequalities related to the determinant to analyze a quadratic equation. How do I analyze a cubic equation for different conditions, like when the equation has one real root, no real root, two equal roots, and all other cases.*

Comment: See the section Trigonometric and Hyperbolic Solutions in the Wikipedia article Cubic Function. These use the identities $\cos (3x)=4(\cos x)^3-3\cos x\;$  and  $\;\cosh (3x)=4(\cosh x)^3-3\cosh x.$ (Where  $\cosh x=(e^x+e^{-x})/2.$ )

Answer (score 3):

An idea: suppose $\;x\;$ is the real root, then:

$$x^3+3x+2xi-1+iy=0\implies\begin{cases}x^3+3x-1=0\\{}\\2x+y=0\end{cases}\implies y=-2x$$

Now, the function $\;x^3+3x-1\;$ is strictly monotone increasing (why?) , and by the MVT it has a root in $\;\left(0,\frac12\right)\;$ which is then its **unique real root** (again, why?) , and thus $\;y\in(-1,0)\;$ , which means...strangely enough, that all the option given in your question are true.

Comment: We have $x^3+3x>1$ for $x\geq 1/3$ so $y\in (-2/3,0)$.... Good answer.